# Limit comparison test; negative outcome

Tags: calculus

It says the outcome must be a positive finite answer, what happens if it's a negative finite answer? Is it inconclusive as if it were 0 or infinity?

Answer (score 3):

If $\lim |a_n/b_n|=0$ and $\sum |b_n|$ converges, then $\sum |a_n|$ converges.  If $\lim |a_n/b_n|=\infty$ and $\sum |a_n|$ diverges, then $\sum |b_n|$ diverges.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how the above answer relates, but in my calculus 3 class our teacher, when he finds a negative result ex: -1/10 when using the limit comparison theorem, he simply combines the theorem with the absolute value theorem that says if the absolute value converges so does the series, so then you get 1/10, which is positive. Combining theorems I believe is the complicated idea here.

Comment: The "above" Answer (the one posted before yours) already includes taking absolute values, but it doesn't address an important aspect of the Question, namely when the limit of absolute ratios is finite.  I urge you to improve your Answer by expanding on the application of the limit comparison test in these cases.  It will make a useful contribution.

Comment: @hardmath, good motivation. Also, the "above" answer's second part must be the other way around. Counterexample, $a_n=n$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$.